# Appending file format while turning text into link (by pressing Enter) in Vimwiki

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

When using the vimwiki plugin, when you want to convert any text into a link you can press `enter` on the selection. Then you follow the link, create the file and work with it.

**The problem:**

When you push files into GitHub, the link is obviously broken, because there are no `link` file - there's `link.md`. How can I automatically append a file extension (`.md`) to the links?

Config:

```
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/knowledge/', 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.md'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/pull/529).
Specifically:

> For those trying to use this you need:
>
> let g:vimwiki_markdown_link_ext = 1

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!